# How can I reference an object value within an array of promises?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, promise

The **Object** below contains lookup keys which contain an **Array** of **Promises** used to run a series of validations against a `value`.

How can the value of `full_name` be accessible from `email`?

```js
const config = {
  full_name: [
    val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(val)),
    val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(val))
  ],
  email: [
    val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(val)),
    val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(`${config.full_name.val}`)) // get the value which has been passed to full_name
  ]
}
```

Comment: It should be possible just like that. But it’s `full_name` not `fullname`.

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted and no.. that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.full_name.val` does not exist, because `config.full_name` is an array with functions that return promises.

The use case here depends on the context of how these functions are invoked. This context is explained here: https://jsfiddle.net/karlbateman/keqnrybq/.

Considering also that the validation part lives in a different module than the actual config, one cannot simply access the formData in the callbacks.

However, you can add a context param to your function callbacks which provides the formData to be accessed, as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/odolha/tpn75570/

See this line (in the validatorFn):

```
arr.push(config[field].map(cb => cb(formData[field], formData)))
```

This basically provides the formData as a context param, which can be used later:

```
(val, ctx) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
  reject(`${ctx.name} already is exists.`) // simulate a HTTP request
}, 2000))
```

Comment: Thank you, great solution although I was hoping to be able to reference the `val` without having to resolve the promise. With your suggestion `config.full_name` would need to resolve `val`.

Comment: I have modified my question to return the value passed to each Promise, with your solution it will fail because `full_name` is being passed a blank value.

Comment: I am also aware that `config.full_name.val` is not possible but used it as an example of what I am hoping to achieve within the `email` array.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve with this? Without the context of how this config is used, it's hard to understand. Are you invoking the full_name function prior to the email function and somehow you want the value passed there to be available later (e.g. when the email promise is finished? )

Comment: In that situation, you already have access to the formData - e.g. just use formData.name

Comment: I don't if the `config` is loaded as a module.

Comment: hmm, well then I guess you could save the value when first invoked e.g. `full_name: [ val => { config._full_name = val; return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(val)) }, `... and then use it on the other promise `... reject(config._full_name` but this is not a very nice approach because you are working under the assumption that the full_name is always called first and only once and you could have concurrency issues if same config is used e.g. for multiple components on the same page, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have access to change the validation code, you could include another param (E.g. context) in the functions, so the validation code will make sure to pass the object to be validated as context ,so the callbacks have access to the data. see https://jsfiddle.net/odolha/tpn75570/ (they can still be in separate modules now)

Comment: By validation code, each promise is validating the `val` associated with the respective key. Thus the validation config is `config`. This can be changed, could you provide an example based on the above?

Comment: see the jsfiddle above

Comment: That's great, did you just add `ctx` as a param?

Comment: Yes, and I'm passing the form object in the validatorFn - in this line `arr.push(config[field].map(cb => cb(formData[field], formData)))` - so formData will become ctx, this way you don't need direct access of formData in your callbacks (so they can live in different modules)

Comment: You sir, are a genius.. thanks for that. Feel free to use that Fiddle to put together an answer, I will gladly accept. Certainly works for my use case ;-)

Comment: Changed the answer to provide context info and added appropriate solution and explanation (summary of comments)

Answer (score 0):

You may also implement a similar functionality as follows;

```js
function promisifier(val, pass = true){
  return new Promise(function(v,x){
                       return pass ? v(val) : x(val);
                     });
}

var config = { full_name: [promisifier, promisifier],
                   email: [promisifier, promisifier]
             };
config.full_name[0]("Thaddeus Jones")
      .then(r => config.email[1](r,false))
      .then(r => console.log("resolved by:", r))
      .catch(e => console.log("received error:", e));
```

Comment: An interesting approach. Although each promise within the array will perform a different action.

Comment: @Karl Bateman Just for clarity I used a dummy promisifier not to repeat the promise returning function over and over. Provided that in the real code your array items are promise returning entities then this pattern should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I need to access the value within the context of `config`, this is actually a module as various configurations can be loaded depending on the input. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/karlbateman/keqnrybq/, for a sample use case.